# How to access the system indices like .kibana* indices in the latest elasticsearch version

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In our project, we have a service that takes the backup of different system indices like .kibana* indices. When I access them using the rest API, I am getting the following deprecation warning:

```
{"type": "deprecation.elasticsearch", "timestamp": "2022-02-17T10:04:04,446Z", "level": "DEPRECATION", "component": "o.e.d.c.m.IndexNameExpressionResolver", "cluster.name": "project-1", "node.name": "elasticsearch", "message": "this request accesses system indices: [.kibana_7.15.2_001], but in a future major version, direct access to system indices will be prevented by default", "key": "open_system_index_access", "cluster.uuid": "47qJK-ibTqS2U83rHQdWiQ", "node.id": "rtXy8ASwQAGKO7pFmWZY9Q" }
```

I am using kibana 7.15.2 and Elasticsearch 7.15.2 but when we shall upgrade Elasticsearch to version 8 i shall not be able to access the system indices using this API:

```
"https://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/.kibana*?h=index"
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

From the Elasticsearch Docs:

> If you must access a system index, create a security role with an
> index permission that targets the specific index and set the
> allow_restricted_indices permission to true

Refer to this for more info : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/current/elasticsearch-breaking-changes.html#_index_setting_changes